# Method GetTokenAsync unavailable

Tags: identityserver4

I´m following the Quickstarts from IdentityServer4. When I implement the "Switching to Hybrid Flow and adding API Access back" tutorial, I found that the method to get the access token in line:

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

is not available. Someone knows what method I must to use? Thanks.

Comment: You should make your comment as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that in my MVC controller I had the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;`. This library allows use the `[Authorize]` attribute but has his own HttpContext.Authentication namespace. The solution is add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` and now I can access to the GetTokenAsync method.